# Airport Express Base Stations as Bridge

Tags: network, wifi, airport

I have two Apple A1264 Airport Express Base Stations. I acquired them from a client I did some work for awhile back who gave me some Apple hardware that he wasn't using anymore as payment since they were struggling. I don't have a huge Apple knowledge base...

Is there a way I can link these two base stations together to create a bridge to connect a wired device to my network across my house? The wall I need to go through doesn't have a good way to run a cable so I'm looking for alternative solutions, I basically want to connect a CAT6 cable from my device to one of the Airport Express stations and then I want to connect a CAT6 cable from my router to the other Airport Express station and have the device be reaching the router.

I searched for a couple of articles and from what I read you can create a WiFi to ethernet bridge using just one of these devices since my router isn't an Apple router. I was hoping someone here may have a creative solution on how I can use both of these devices to accomplish my task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do this with the "Extend a wireless network" option within the Airport Extreme, but a better solution may be to use power adapters to extend your network.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept the answer. I was working on testing this when life got busy and I dropped it. I was able to successfully do this after I updated the firmware on the device to the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

You can plug in one into a router on the network side and configure that Airport Express it as to create a wireless network (i.e. that Airport will make a WLAN with name and password).  You can test that part if with a mobile phone or laptop you can log into that WLAN to access your stuff there.

Then with the device side, configure it's WLAN as "Join existing network" and give it the name and login credentials of the other.  You may have to provide the device with a static IP address though that would fit into the LAN on the other side.